# xStation: Trying to connect SSL server via PHP Socket client

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I am having problem in establishing a SSL connection to remote server using PHP socket client.

Connecting to simple socket server is easy but SSL connection is keeping a live and doesn't respond anything, please look at the code below and guide me what mistake I am doing in the following code.

Page is keep loading but doesn't respond anything.

```
// command array
$command = array(
    'command' => 'login',
    'arguments' => array(
        'userId' => 'xxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxx',
        'appId' => 'test',
        'appName' => 'test',
    ),
);

$fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://xapia.x-station.eu:5124", $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    die("Unable to connect: $errstr ($errno)");
}

/* Turn on encryption for login phase */
fwrite($fp, json_encode($command));

while ($motd = fgets($fp)) {
    echo $motd;
    echo '<hr />';
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: it works for me, I get {"errorCode":"BE005","errorDescr":"userPasswordCheck: Invalid login or password.","status":false}
<hr />
<hr />  when run from command line.

Comment: But it's not working for me, I am not getting anything may be it's due to some server setting or anything else do you know something about it?

Comment: Is it hanging for you from command line?  You should use wireshark to see what's going on.  Perhaps there is DNS failure?  Can you hit that site+port in any other way, maybe the target site or ISP is blocking you?

Comment: It's running fine from command line, but I am using XAMPP and accessing it from browser something like http://localhost/test.php but it's keep running don't know why.

Comment: Then there's a server setting problem.  What are the differences from the CLI php flags and the Server php flags?  can you dump phpinfo() from the server and php -i from command line and look at settings like allow_url_fopen and other stream settings?

Comment: but an echo "something\n' after each php line and flush() call to figure out exactly where it hangs.  Is it hanging on stream_Socket_client()?  fwrite() or fgets() ?

Comment: also try restarting your whole apache.  there could be something hanging in the background clogging up port 5124 from previous script versions that didn't properly close the connection?

Comment: Can you please check and figure out the problem with my server settings? please have a look at PHP info here on testing server http://uakk4a900476.azharnt.koding.io/test.php

Comment: looks fine to me, stream and fopen setting match with my CLI settings.  i have 5.5.9-1ubuntu-4.9 that's the only difference.  Restart the web server, sounds like something is hanging.

Comment: It's seems that while loop is not stopping due to some reason like server is not closing the connection and while loop is keep trying to get the contents, I just remove the while loop and add this code which is working fine "echo $motd = fgets($fp, 1024);"